# Switch Expression in read only property

Tags: c#

I have a switch expression for a property in a class:

```
public class InitialMargin
{
    // ... properties
    public string Measure { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal? MarketValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? Margin => Measure switch
    {
        "Flat" => Amount,
        "MarketValue" => Amount * MarketValue,
        _ => default
    };
}

public enum InitialMarginMeasure
{
    Flat,
    MarketValue
}
```

If I want to use the `enum` in the `Margin` property, the code does not compile, so I would like to understand the reason for that.

```
    public decimal? Margin => Measure switch
    {
        InitialMarginMeasure.Flat.ToString() => Amount,
        InitialMarginMeasure.MarketValue.ToString() => Amount * MarketValue,
        _ => default
    };
```

Comment: And without the ToString, changing the type of Measure as well?

Comment: The values to switch on must be compile time constants

Comment: Why not change the type of `Measure` to be `InitialMarginMeasure` and then you don't need to keep converting?

Comment: `Enum.Parse<InitialMarginMeasure>(Measure ) switch ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `nameof`:

```
public decimal? Margin => Measure switch
{
    nameof (InitialMarginMeasure.Flat) => Amount,
    nameof (InitialMarginMeasure.MarketValue) => Amount * MarketValue,
    _ => default
};
```

`ToString()` is <s>an instance method</s> a runtime method, so does not work because the switch requires a compile-time constant.

Comment: ToString() is a runtime method, while nameof() is compile time - that's the important difference here

Comment: `nameof` works in this case. But why I am able to create a property using `enum JobStatus` like this in a class : `public string Status { get; set; } = JobStatus.Running.ToString();`

Comment: As @HansKeﬆing has mentioned above, the difference is the context. The switch requires a compile time constant: the compiler needs to know what the value is so that it can create the appropriate IL code, and `nameof` lets you do that. Your property assignment is happening at run-time, when the class gets initialised.